# Do something if any operational parameter is set in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using this Route for optional parameters:

```
Route::get('/{place?}/{day?}', 'Weather@fetch_weather');
```

I want the controller to execute a code if either of the parameter is present or even if none are passed.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public function fetch_weather ($place = null, $day = null) {
    if ($place) {
        if ($day) {
            //do something with provided place and provided 1 specific day
        } else {
            //do something with provided place but with 7 days
        }
    } else {
    if ($day) {
        //do something with automatic place and provided specific day
    } else {
        //do something with automatic place and 7 days
    }
}
```

Now if someone provides ONE parameter, how is laravel supposed to know if it is a place or a day.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not possible, laravel will always take the first route parameter and put it in the first function parameter

Comment: So I guess all I can do is to use a trivial switch case to alternate the values if the only parameter provided looks like a day? Right?

Comment: Well there are two ways for this to be done : you could either put the place and day as get params like ?place=...&day=... or you could put different routes like /place/{place}, /day/{day} and a third one for the place and the day. For the first method, you only have one controller function. As for the second method, you can use three different controller method that call your main controller function that does the job

Comment: I just thought about it, you can also check the format of the argument. For example, if $place is a date, you know that it is $day and not $place

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot for the answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @AlexvanVliet You can post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Oh thanks, doing it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have three options :

1) You can create three different routes :

```
/place/{place} calls controller@place
/day/{day} calls controller@day
/placeandday/{day}/{place} controller&placeAndDay
```

And each method just calls and returns your `fetch_weather` with the proper arguments.

2) You can put the place and day as get parameters and have them with `$request->get('day')` and `$request->get('place')`

3) You can have only one route like this :

```
/weather/{first_arg}/{second_arg?}
```

You just have to check whether the second_arg is null or not and what the format of first_arg is:

- if first_arg is a day and second_arg null : you only have the day
- if first_arg is not a day and second_arg null : you only have the place
- if first_arg is a day and second_arg not null : you have the day as first_arg and the place as second_arg
- if first_arg is not a day and second_arg not null : you have the place as first_arg and the day as second_arg

I think the 3rd one is the closest to what you want to achieve, but requires slightly more code